# Looping on multiple elements and add a wrapper to each of them

Tags: javascript

While waiting for people to come for Christmas, I tried to start a floatlabel-like library with vanilla JS. And I'm stuck on the part where I add a wrapper around the inputs

```
var materialFloatLabel = function(o) {
  o = (typeof o === 'undefined') ? '' : o;

  var lib = {
    // Just for the futur settings
    settings: {
      selector: o.selector ? o.selector : '.matFloat'
    },

    // Getting the inputs
    inputs: function() {
      return document.querySelectorAll(this.settings.selector);
    },

    // Adding a specific class to each input so it can easily be selected later 
    addWrapper: function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.inputs().length; i++) {
        this.inputs()[i].className = this.inputs()[i].className + ' materialFloatLabel' + i;
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.appendChild(this.inputs()[i]);
        // ERROR DOWN HERE
        document.querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel' + i).parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, document.querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel' + i));
      }
    },

    init: function() {
      this.addWrapper();
    }
  };

  return lib.init();
};

(function() {
  materialFloatLabel();
})();
```

The current error I'm stuck on is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of undefined` And I can't manage to go through it. Any idea?

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Axiol/18fxv7yr/) to check it live

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a **nodeList**, not a single element, and a nodeList has no parentNode ?

Comment: @adeneo Correct, but using `querySelector` doesn't change anything. But thanks, I already changed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel' + i)[0]
```

Even if there is only one element returned.

According to [MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
// elementList is a non-live NodeList of element objects.
```

And `NodeList` is some [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

---

In the code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.inputs().length; i++) {
    this.inputs()[i].className = this.inputs()[i].className + ' materialFloatLabel' + i;
    // Create a Node, which is NOT on DOM yet.
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');   
    // MOVE the input to the new Node, so the input is not on DOM anymore!
    wrapper.appendChild(this.inputs()[i]);         
    // Since the input is not on DOM, querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel' + i) returns []
    document.querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel' + i)[0].parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, document.querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel' + i)[0]);
}
```

**You cannot query the input after adding the new class because the input is not on the DOM anymore.** Please be noted that `appendChild` will MOVE the node to a new place ([MDN Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)). Since you are moving the input to `wrapper`, which is not on DOM yet, your `querySelectorAll` returns empty.

### And more

Don't perform `this.input()` everytime, because your DOM is changing. If your are not careful, your loop may become a mess. Since the result of `querySelectorAll` is not-live, you can keep your selection results consistent.

More importantly, to achieve better performance, it is better to store the intermediate results in some variables.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/18fxv7yr/1/

Comment: Yes, I already tried this one. But when I try this, it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`. Which is weird because if I stop the code before, the `inputs` correctly have the classes.

Comment: Put some JSFiddle. Your DOM may not have that element with class `'.materialFloatLabel' + i` based on the error message

Comment: By searching `materialFloatLabel` in the HTML source, I did not find any elements with `class=materialFloatLabel`. On the console, type in `document.querySelectorAll('.materialFloatLabel0')` returns `[]`

Comment: It's normal, those classes are added on the first line of `for`.